# Use IdentityServer4 with external Active Directory on Windows Server 2008R2

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, identityserver4

An external partner wants to authenticate on our systems, using Active Directory.
We want to use that Active Directory as an external provider in IdentityServer4.
Unfortunately the AD at their location only runs on Windows Server 2008R2 (functional level 2003)
What are our best options here to integrate with IdentityServer4?

Comment: Sorry, need more detail? What difference does the level of AD make to idsrv4? Are they going to use idsrv4 on their side? Is that what you use?

Comment: We are using idsrv4 on our side and we want to plug in another identityprovider to support authentication against their AD.

Comment: For this, you add the WS-Fed plugin to idsrv4 and then federate with their ADFS. (Not sure if .NET Core has full cryptography support yet for WS-Fed?).

Comment: I'm not talking about ADFS here. I want to use AD without ADFS, so I guess I just need to execute LDAP queries?

Comment: Does idsrv4 have an AD plugin? Custom code is not a good idea. How will you chose where to authenticate? Most companies do not allow external AD access through the firewall for security reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply "turn on" Windows authentication in IdentityServer.

See the docs:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/windows.html

If the Windows authentication should happen on a different machine than the one where your (main) identityserver is installed, create a "mini identityserver" that runs on a machine joined to the right domain and federate with it using OpenID Connect.

The whole purpose of that "mini IS" would be to turn a Windows token into a JWT (very similar to what ADFS does in a nutshell).

Comment: The AD that we want to use is not in our organization, so we can't just use Windows authentication and ADFS is also not an option.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Seems to be the most "clean" solution indeed

Comment: the above link doesn't have any content. showing 'this page does not exist yet'

Answer (score 0):

If Identityserver4 has win os 2008R2, ask them if they can raise their funct level to 2008 on that server, this would solve integration issues in the simplest way, assuming that all their servers funct level can be raised to 2008.